# Surfaces of genus g

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The problem: give maps $f:\Sigma_{g}\longrightarrow\Sigma_{h}$ not homotopic to a constant map with $0<g<h$.

Any idea would be helpful.

Comment: If you can find a group homomorphism from $\pi_1\Sigma_g\to\pi_1\Sigma_h$, that does not send all of the elements of $\pi_1\Sigma_g$ to the identity, you will find such a map.

Comment: Crush a subsurface to a point.

Comment: Maybe you could be a little more precise. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean $0 < h < g$ (i.e., mapping higher genus to lower)?

Comment: @R.Bradley: Find a subsurface of genus $h-g$ with one boundary component, and then form the quotient space where all of the points in this subsurface are identified to a point. The resulting surface is homeomorphic to $\Sigma_g$. If you look at the induced map on homology it is nontrivial.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang $0<g<h$ is correct.

Comment: Grumpy Parsnip's second comment is an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of such a map is guaranteed by $K(G,1)$ theory because $\Sigma_g$ is aspherical for $g\geq 1$. To construct a map explicitly, try to come up with a map from the torus to $\Sigma_2$, which is not homotopic to the constant map. For a hint, try flattening the torus to an annulus first, then map the annulus into $\Sigma_2$ in a homotopically non-trivial way.